# How do you open multiple files with dash'-' at the start of filename?

Tags: shell, find, filenames

I am able to open on file at a time using `cat -- -file00` but I want to open multiple files at once. Tried using find, can't figure it out.

```
find ./ -name '*.txt' exec cat {} \;

find ./ -name '*.txt' exec grep 'inhere' {} \;
```

None of this working. I have multiple files in the dir in this form:
-file00 -file01 -file03
-file04 -file05 -file06

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-name '*.txt'` is to match on files whose name ends in `.txt`. That won't match yours. Use a pattern that matches your files:

```
find . -name '-file*' -exec cat {} +
```

Or

```
cat ./-file*
```

if they are all in the current directory (would also have the benefit of concatenating those files ordered alphabetically contrary to `find` which list files in random order).

Note that the `--` is not needed above as the arguments passed to `cat` all start with `./`, not `-`.

For a more specific match (only `-file` followed by exactly two decimal digits): `./-file[0-9][0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `xargs` if you'd like.

```
find ./ -name '-file0*' | xargs cat
```

As noted above none of your files actually have `.txt` as an extension. If they did you could replace `-file0*` with `*.txt`